# how to change facebook fanpage signature text and link

Tags: facebook

I wants to change or Edit my Fanpages signature.

When any feed posted to my fanpage there is an signature under the Description with started with via text appname with link.

How do i change the appname and appname link in the signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'via X' is the app name, and links to the app.
You can change both in the app settings; the link to the app will be your canvas or website